# Double.ToString("N") rules on rounding

Tags: .net

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double roundUp = 55.329;
        double roundDown = 55.324;
        double awayFromZero = 55.325;
        Console.WriteLine("round up:" + roundUp.ToString("N"));
        Console.WriteLine("round down:" + roundDown.ToString("N"));
        Console.WriteLine("round away from zero:" + awayFromZero.ToString("N"));
    }
}
```

Result
round up:55.33 
round down:55.32
round away from zero:55.33

cut and pasted from dotnetfiddle.net (https://dotnetfiddle.net/TnOaXF).

My question is I am looking at [double.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) in the msdn and cannot find out where the "rules" are determining rounding. How does double.toString determing to use round away from zero vs round to zero? Any link to the msdn or another authoritative site would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Side note: dotnetfiddle doesn't require a login, just click "Share". Either way, it's good practice to paste the code here, in case dotnetfiddle goes bankrupt and we're left with nothing but broken links.

Comment: @dcastro thank you very much. I was hitting save and assumed that would give me a url also

Comment: Assuming `decimal` is rounded using the same method as `double`, found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2249573/4019710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Standard Numeric Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) docs, it's always away from zero:

> To perform a rounding operation, use the Math.Ceiling, Math.Floor, or Math.Round method.
>
> When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result strings reflect numbers that are rounded away from zero (that is, using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).

From that page, and from the [Custom Numeric Format Strings page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) it doesn't look like there's a way to override this: if you want something else, you'll have to manually round the number before formatting.